# How many structures in clash of clans can I build

Tags: clash-of-clans

How many of each structure can I build in clash of clans.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the building in question and your town hall level.

For instance, for Cannons, you can build 2 until town hall 5, when you can build a third.  Town hall 7 adds 2 more for a total of 5, and you get one more at town hall 10 for a total of 6.

There is a table [on this Wikia page](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Hall) which lists the buildings available by town hall level.